# how to write a loop in XML?

Tags: xml

I have an XML file like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <field name="age" type="list"
    default="1"
    description="age"
    label="Age"
    size="1"
    >
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>

    </field>
</form>
```

I need to repeat the option for a fixed number of times. How can I write a loop to repeat the option? Is it possible to write a loop?

Comment: Program XML is like drive a street. You need a car, or in your case, a programming language. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Andreas Hey, I love this comparison. It will be great to have in mind to explain what XML don't do.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I write a loop to repeat the option? Is it possible to write a loop?

**No, XML is a markup language, not a programming language.** The only way to have 4 of something is to replicate it 4 times.

Answer (score -1):

Via php

/* $xmlstr your xml string */

```
$options = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

/* For each <character> node, we echo a separate <name>. */
foreach ($options->options as $option) {
   echo $option->value, $character->actor, PHP_EOL;
}
```